# Not being able to authenticate Google Visualization Query Language with given Authentication Key

Tags: php, authentication, curl, gdata-api, google-sheets

Not being able to authenticate Google Spreadsheet API.
I'm using this code stolen from [here](http://kovshenin.com/archives/google-docs-api-client-login-with-php-and-curl/),

```
$clientlogin_url = "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin";
$clientlogin_post = array(
    "accountType" => "HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE",
    "Email"   => "MY_EMAIL@GOOGLE.COM",
    "Passwd"  => "MY_EMAIL_PASS",
    "service" => "writely",
    "source"  => "MY_APPLICATION_NAME"
);

// Initialize the curl object
$curl = curl_init($clientlogin_url);

// Set some options (some for SHTTP)
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $clientlogin_post);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// Execute
$response = curl_exec($curl);

// Get the Auth string and save it
preg_match("/Auth=([a-z0-9_\-]+)/i", $response, $matches);
$auth = $matches[1];

echo "The auth string is: " . $auth; //this worked!
```

**So this works and now I have a key** But actually using it...with the bellow code gives me a user not authenticated error:

```
$headers = array(
    "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=" . $auth,
    "GData-Version: 3.0",
);

$key = 'MY_KEY';

// Make the request
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?tqx=version:0.6;out:json&key='.$key);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);


var_dump ($response);
```

this gives me

```
string(272) "google.visualization.Query.setResponse({version:'0.6',status:'error',errors:[{reason:'user_not_authenticated',message:'User not signed in',detailed_message:'\u003ca target=\u0022_blank\u0022 href=\u0022http://spreadsheets.google.com/\u0022\u003eSign in\u003c/a\u003e'}]});"
```

So apparently it is not able to use the authentication key for the [Google Visualization Query Language](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/querylanguage.html).. what am I doing wrong?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following modifications in the code that uses google authentication string:

add `urlencode`

```
$headers = array(  
   "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=" . urlencode($auth),  
   "GData-Version: 3.0",  
);
```

and skip verifying SSL sertificates:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
```

I've described my experience implementing authentication with CURL in this [post](http://kniganapolke.wordpress.com/2009/10/08/form-autorization-curl-php/). There you'll find some tips on debugging CURL requests.